# Fetch data from database either with a stored procedure or a query

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedure

I have this method, `GetDataAsync()`, that grabs data from the database using a stored procedure if `sqlToRun` Dictionary contains the table name. If not, then there is no stored procedure to run and just grab the table from the db directly (no SP) and convert it to a C# object to use.

Here's the code:

```
private async Task<Response> GetDataAsync(string table, int? start, int? end)
{
    if (_sqlToRun.ContainsKey(table))
    {
        var sql = _sqlToRun[table];
        var data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var resp = new Response();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

            var startParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@startRowNum",
                Value = start,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add(startParam);

            var endParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@endRowNum",
                Value = end,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add(endParam);
            var outputParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@recordCount", SqlDbType.Int);
            outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using (var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await rdr.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, rdr.FieldCount))
                    {
                        var dbValue = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rdr.GetValue(i).ToString()) == true
                            ? string.Empty
                            : rdr.GetValue(i);

                        dictionary.Add(rdr.GetName(i), dbValue);
                    }

                    data.Add(dictionary);
                }
            }

            Int32.TryParse(cmd.Parameters["@recordCount"].Value.ToString(), out var recordCount);
            resp.Data = data;
            resp.RecordCount = recordCount;
        }

        return resp;
    }
    else
    {
        var data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var resp = new Response();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = "Select * from " + table;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using (var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await rdr.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, rdr.FieldCount))
                    {
                        var dbValue = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rdr.GetValue(i).ToString()) == true
                            ? string.Empty
                            : rdr.GetValue(i);

                        dictionary.Add(rdr.GetName(i), dbValue);
                    }

                    data.Add(dictionary);
                }
            }

            Int32.TryParse(cmd.Parameters["@recordCount"].Value.ToString(), out var recordCount);
            resp.Data = data;
            resp.RecordCount = recordCount;
        }

        return resp;
    }
}
```

Where Response is below:

```
public class Response
{
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

How can I improve this code and refactor it?

Comment: i don't get the purpose of await rdr.ReadAsync()

Answer (score 3):

My C# is quite rusty, so take everything I'm saying with a grain of salt; I stand by the general principles of what I'm writing, but the syntax/style might be a little off.

---

The first problem is that the two branches of your function are identical except for the `SqlCommand` being used. You should factor out how you create the `SqlCommand` and then do the rest the same way. For example,

```
private SqlCommand GetSqlCommandFromTableIfExists(string table, int? start, int? end, SqlConnection conn, string default)
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
    if (_sqlToRun.ContainsKey(table))
    {
        string sql = _sqlToRun[table];
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

        var startParam = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@startRowNum",
            Value = start,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
        };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(startParam);

        var endParam = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@endRowNum",
            Value = end,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
        };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(endParam);
        var outputParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@recordCount", SqlDbType.Int);
        outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    } 
    else
    {
        // You could easily not make the default a parameter if you prefer
        cmd = new SqlCommand(default, conn);
    }

    return cmd;
}
```

Then your function becomes

```
private async Task<Response> GetDataAsync(string table, int? start, int? end)
{

    var data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    var resp = new Response();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
    {
        var cmd = GetSqlCommandFromTableIfExists(table, start, end, conn, "SELECT * FROM " + table);
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (await rdr.ReadAsync())
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, rdr.FieldCount))
                {
                    var dbValue = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rdr.GetValue(i).ToString()) == true
                        ? string.Empty
                        : rdr.GetValue(i);

                    dictionary.Add(rdr.GetName(i), dbValue);
                }

                data.Add(dictionary);
            }
        }

        Int32.TryParse(cmd.Parameters["@recordCount"].Value.ToString(), out var recordCount);
        resp.Data = data;
        resp.RecordCount = recordCount;
    }

    return resp;
}
```

---

### Type unsafety is bad

Right now you're using a raw `object` as the value-type in your dictionary and `Response` - why? I assume its because this is a general function that is independent of the data you're grabbing, but it means you're losing out on what data you're adding and any kind of type safety. I think making the function and your `Response` type generic, and tweaking your implementation, you can ensure type-safety.

---

Don't make some random `data` object; just use `resp.Data`.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically written a very crude ORM using ADO.NET, including some very odd functionality where the table name that is passed can actually be a stored procedure, and the next person who'll have to maintain your code will curse at you for doing so. Presenting your results as a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` is helping nobody, because then this will need to be translated to meaningful objects anyway.

You should abandon this "generic" approach and instead use an ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) or [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723.aspx). Those are skills enterprises look for. Don't waste your time on re-inventing the wheel. ["Unless you’re Ayende or Greg Young, you should not write your own ORM. ... If you’re writing ADO.Net code by hand, you’re stealing from your employer or client."](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/24/dont-write-your-own-orm/).